# Mongodb connection issue with java

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

i am having mongoDB connections issue in java , this is my connection class

```
    public MongoDbUtil() {
    try {
       System.out.println("1");
    String host = "127.0.0.1"  ; 
    String dbName = "m_prod" ; 
    int port =27017 ; 
       System.out.println("2");
    Mongo m = new Mongo();
       System.out.println("3");
    ds = new Morphia().createDatastore(m,dbName);
       System.out.println("4");
    ds.ensureIndexes(); 
       System.out.println("5");
    ds.ensureCaps();
       System.out.println("1");
    } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("catch");            
    }finally{
       System.out.println("finally");
       System.out.println(ds==null);
    } }
```

only 1 and 2 is printing, after that 'finally' is printing also 'ds' is null, there is no any  exception happen ('catch' is not printing)

Mongo server is up and running and i can access from command prompt (Linux) , the Other interesting thing is, its working fine when i call this method by unit test function, but for all other cases above issue happen , what can be the reason ?

Thanks

Comment: Try if `catch (Throwable e)` (instead of `catch(Exception e)`) shows some errors.

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace(). Otherwise your catch block is useless for any error information.

Comment: @Kayaman : program is not coming to catch block even , its not printing 'catch' which prints inside catch block

Comment: @nutlike : you are correct when i put Throwable it prints a error , its telling that 'com.mongodb.Mongo: method <init>()V not found' at the line which creates 'm' object (Mongo m = new Mongo();)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Mongo()` is deprecated, you should use `MongoClient()` instead - see [http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#Mongo()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#Mongo%28%29)
2. Still it should find the deprecated constructor. Can you include the imports of your file, please?

Comment: Thanks, what is the Package of 'MongoClient' class exist, i am using mongo java driver 3.0.0 ?

Comment: Are you sure about 3.0.0? The [latest version](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mongodb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mongo-java-driver%22) should be *2.11.2*. ``MongoClient()`` is a wrapper around ``Mongo()`` with safer default settings. ``Mongo()`` is still available for backwards compatibility, but shouldn't be used any longer.

Comment: I am try to update the version, but having a problem with Morphia version, i am using morphia 0.91 which used mongo-java-driver:2.8.0 ,because of that i cant add mongo-java-driver:2.11.2 dependency to my pom.xml file

Comment: Update to the latest Morphia release: [0.101.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.morphia%7Cmorphia%7C0.101.0%7Cjar). 0.91 must be really old...

Comment: Thanks to all , issue was fix by updating Morphia to 0.11.0 and java driver to 2.11.2 , thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the 3.0 driver, there's a driver-compat layer that will help you transition.  You really should use the new API, though.

Comment: Related to this: Do you provide a SNAPSHOT / alpha / beta of the Java driver? And how does it work in combination with Morphia?

Comment: We're just starting the process of testing morphia against the 3.0 driver.  We're down to 4 test failures 2 of which are caused by the same issue.  I'm not sure about public snapshots but I'll ask.

Comment: If you add this repository to your pom, you can get the 3.0 snapshot builds  https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots with this dependency:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>